# Why is this regex cutting at the start of the line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to cut a word at the first soft hyphen after 5 characters, hyphens included:

This is what I came up with:

```
new RegExp("^(.{5}[^\u00AD]+)\u00AD")
```

It almost works but adds an extra cut at the start of the string:

```
un­-con­-ven­-tion-­al.
[ '', 'un­con', 'ven­tion­al.' ]
sev­en-­teen-year-old
[ '', 'sev­en', 'teen-year-old' ]
```

What I would like is:

```
['un­con', 'ven­tion­al.' ]
```

sometimes it also does not work like this.

```
com­-pa­ny-en­-cou-r­aged
[ '', 'com', 'pa­ny-en­cour­aged' ]
Rev-­o­lu-­tion-­ar­ies,”
[ '', 'Rev', 'o­lu­tion­ar­ies,”' ]
```

should be

```
['compa­ny''en­cour­aged' ]
['Revo­lu","­tion­ar­ies,”' ]
```

Basically, go to character five, continue until you find a hyphen, cut there.

this is how I use it:

```
console.log(hyphened);
console.log(hyphened.split(new RegExp("^(.{6}[^\u00AD]+)\u00AD")));
```

Comment: the soft hyphen( \u00AD) is reoplaced by a hard hyphen in the examples, cause you can't se them otherwise ^^

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work all of the time.

Comment: Could you, please, provide output samples based on the two inputs you have in the description? It's not 100% clear how to guess the output by looking at the lists of tokens.

Comment: This regex works fine and doesn't get me anything like the match groups shown in your example, so we need to see more context of how you are using the regex to get to the output.

Comment: In the latest ECMAScript, `s.split(/(?<=^.{5}[^\u00AD]+)\u00AD/)` should work. Or, use `var match = s.match(/^(.{5}[^\u00AD]+)\u00AD([\s\S]*)/)` and grab `match[1]` and `match[2]`

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko updated question!

Comment: @tgies updated question!

Comment: regex101.com is your friend

Comment: Wait, you mean the `\xAD` should NOT be counted towards the chars matched with `.{5}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx so much! neither work on this word though: Rev­o­lu­tion­ar­ies,”. I'm parsing e-books so it could be all sorts of characters in there..

Comment: no \xAD can be counted :)

Comment: But the problem is with revolutionary - there is a `\xAD`  as the 4th char, then `o` is the 5th, then comes `\xAD` to split on, right? Please reconsider your requirements, or rephrase/precise them.

Comment: I am afraid you messed the test cases. Please post them with `"rev\xAD..."` notation. `.match(/^(.{5}[^\u00AD]*)\u00AD([\s\S]*)/)` seems to work. See [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/vthhkT).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works great if you put up an answer i'll give you the credit and we'll get a nice q&a! I tried running it on another word. In node on my machine, `console.log(str.match(/^(.{8}[^\u00AD]*)\u00AD([\s\S]*)/))` outputs null, any idea why. It works on ideone, though.  https://ideone.com/51oifQ

Comment: Since you can't repro it is not a real issue. Check the input variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var strs = ["un\xADcon\xADven\xADtion\xADal.","seven\xADteen\xADyear\xADold","com\xADpany\xADen\xADcou\xADraged","Rev\xADolu\xADtion\xADaries"]
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  var match = strs[i].match(/^([\s\S]{5}[^\u00AD]*)\u00AD([\s\S]*)/);
  if (match) {
    console.log(strs[i], "=>", match[1].replace(/\xAD/g, '-'), ",", match[2].replace(/\xAD/g, '-'));
  }
}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([\s\S]{5}[^\u00AD]*)` - Group 1: any 5 chars and then 0+ chars other than the soft hyphen
- `\u00AD` - a soft hyphen
- `([\s\S]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars.